How to handle both user does not exist and wrong password cases differently in firebase Jetpack compose
override suspend fun signIn(email: String, password: String): Flow<Response<Boolean>> =
    callbackFlow {
        try {
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        trySend(Response.Success(true))
                        val user = auth.currentUser
                    } else {
                        try {
                            throw task.exception!!
                        } catch (e: FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            trySend(Response.Failure(e))
                        }
                    }
                }
            trySend(Response.Loading)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            trySend(Response.Failure(e))
        }

        awaitClose { }
    }

I want to handle cases of user does not exist and wrong password , firebase is throwing same exception in both cases so how to differentiate both cases and let the user know why the sign in failed?

Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired


I believe that, in general, current best practice is not to distinguish those two cases.  Doing so would give an attacker useful information.  (In particular,  it'd tell them almost immediately whether standard usernames like ‘admin’ or ‘root’ are set up.  They could also quickly check for common names etc.  They could then try to crack the corresponding passwords separately.)  (Disclaimer: I'm not a security pro.)

On projects created since September 15 2023, Firebase has auto-enabled its protection against email enumeration attack. One of the consequences of that protection is that it's no longer possible between user does not exist and wrong password.
You will either have to disable the protection against email enumeration attacks or forego the use-case.
